# Failed to import App engine DatastoreService using Android Studio Beta (0.8.1)

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, google-cloud-datastore

```
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
```

I migrated my App Engine Java servlet module from Eclipse Kepler to Android Studio using the Export to -> build.gradle from Eclipse.

The problem is that Android Studio doesnt recognize the imports mentioned above.

I already did the following:

-Updated the corresponding build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.6'
}
```

}

(...)

```
dependencies {
```

appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.6'
  compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5' }

I downloaded the Android Support repository from the SDK
I also tried to find the  jars needed from the download jar from web, option, after clicking on the Datastoreservice Datastore =...

The module I created in Android Studio is the proper module for a Java Http Servlet.

Any ideas, how to import the appengine datastore service using build.gradle or by any other method?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Found it!

Just added the following to my build.gradle file and the imports were successful. Although the app-engine endpoints seem irrelevant, the com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService; was imported

```
dependencies {
appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.1'
compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.1'
compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.1'
compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'}
```